# Align p:graphicImage to center inside p:column

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm developing a test JSF project in PrimeFaces 6.0.
There should be few icons positioned in a table-like structure and centered.
I tried using p:panelGrid with p:row and p:column to create a table-like structure, and p:graphicImage for displaying icons.

The issue is to have p:graphicImage centered inside a cell, i.e. inside a p:column.

Sample of my code is below, and it's not providing the desired result.

```
<p:panelGrid id="pgIcons" style="width: 100%;">
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="width: 34%; text-align: center;">
            <p:graphicImage id="gi1" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-check"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width: 33%; text-align: center;">
            <p:graphicImage id="gi2" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-bookmark"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width: 33%; text-align: center;">
            <p:graphicImage id="gi3" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-tag"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: CSS class : `.centered td {text-align: center;}` then specify `styleClass="centered"` with `<p:panelGrid>` (i.e. `<p:panelGrid styleClass="centered" ...>`).

Comment: Thanks for posting. Unfortunately, it is not working... that is, I discovered that it would be working only if p:graphicImage doesn't have styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-..." specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of testing, I've come up to a solution.

It appears that in this case the main problem is not how to set alignment in cell (*p:column*), which can be done in either of the proposed ways (with *style="text-align: center;"* or with *style="margin: 0px auto;"*).

The main issue here is that *p:graphicImage* has *styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-..."*. Without that styleClass (and by using *src="..."* to specify image source), the cell alignment would be applied without any problems.

If *styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-..."* has to be used, then it's needed to specify additional style for *p:graphicImage* to cope with it, and this style is **style="display: block; margin: 0px auto;"**.

```
<p:panelGrid id="pgIcons" style="width: 100%;">
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="width: 50%; text-align: center;">
            <p:graphicImage id="gi1" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-check" 
                style="display: block; margin: 0px auto;"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width: 50%; margin: 0px auto;">
            <p:graphicImage id="gi2" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-bookmark"
                style="display: block; margin: 0px auto;"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:column styleClass="centered">
    <p:graphicImage id="gi1" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-check"/>
</p:column>

CSS

.centered td {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, it was useful to read your answer. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue. I have later discovered that it would be working only if p:graphicImage doesn't have styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-..." specified.